# Need help implementing a certain logic that will fill a text to a certain width.

Tags: c++, loops, vector, logic

The task is to justify text within a certain width.

```
user inputs: Hello my name is Harrry. This is a sample text input that nobody 
             will enter.

output: What text width do you want?

user inputs: 15

output: |Hello  my  name|
        |is Harrry. This| 
        |is   a   sample|
        |text       that| 
        |nobody     will|
        |enter.         |
```

Basically, the line has to be 15 spaces wide including blank spaces. Also, if the next word in the line cant fit into 15, it will skip entirely. If there are multiple words in a line, it will try to distribute the spaces evenly between each word. See the line that says "Is a sample" for example.

I created a vector using getline(...) and all that and the entire text is saved in a vector. However, I'm kind of stuck on moving forward. I tried using multiple for loops, but I just cant seem to skip lines or even out the spacing at all.

Again, not looking or expecting anyone to solve this, but I'd appreciate it if you could guide me into the right direction in terms of logic/algorithm i should think about.

Comment: You need to provide some samples of what you did already to show your effort to get the help you need. Please take a look at [How to ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to get a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider this *Dynamic programming* solution.

Split text into “good” lines

Since we don't know where we need to break the line for good justification, we start guessing where the break to be done to the paragraph. (That is we guess to determine whether we should break between two words and make the second word as start of the next line).

You notice something? We brutefore!

And note that if we can't find a word small enought to fit in the remaining space in the current line, we insert spaces inbetween the words in the current line. So, the space in the current line depends on the words that might go into the next or previous line. That's Dependency!

You are bruteforcing and you have dependency,there comes the DP!

Now lets define a state to identify the position on our path to solve this problem.

**State**:  **[i : j]**  ,which denotes line of words from ith word to jth word in the original sequence of words given as input.

Now, that you have state for the problem let us try to define how these **states are related**.

Since all our sub-problem states are just a pile of words, we can't just compare the words in each state and determine **which one is better**. Here *better* delineates to the use of line's width to hold maximum character and minimum spaces between the words in the particular line. So, we define a parameter, that would measure the goodness of  the list of words from ith to jth words to make a line. (recall our definition of subproblem state). This is basically evaluating each of our subproblem state.

A simple comparison factor would be :

Define **badness(i, j)** for line of words[i : j].

For example,
Infinity if total length > page width,
else (page width − total length of words in current line)3

To make things even simple consider only suffix of the given text and apply this algorithm. This would reduce the DP table size from N*N to N.

So, For finishing lets make it clear what we want in DP terms,

1. **subproblem** = min. badness for suffix words[i :]

   =⇒ No.of subproblems = Θ(n) where n = no of words
2. **guessing** = where to end first line, say i : j

   =⇒ no. of  choices for j = n − i = O(n)
3. **recurrence relation** between the subproblem:

   • DP[i] = min(badness (i, j) + DP[j] for j in range (i + 1, n + 1))
   • DP[n] = 0

=⇒ time per subproblem = Θ(n)

so, total time = Θ(n^2).

Also, I'll leave it to you how insert spaces between words after determining the words in each line.

Answer (score 0):

Logic would be:

1) Put words in array

2) Loop though array of words

3) Count the number of chars in each word, and check until they are the text width or less (skip if more than textwidth). Remember the number of words that make up the total before going over 15 (example remember it took 3 words to get 9 characters, leaving space for 6 spaces)

4) Divide the number of spaces required by (number of words - 1)

5) Write those words, writing the same number of spaces each time.

Should give the desired effect I hope.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have some idea how to solve this, as you have already produced the sample output.

Perhaps re-solve your original problem writing down in words what you do in each step....

e.g.

1. Print text asking for sentence.
2. Take input
3. Split input into words.
4. Print text asking for width.
5. ...

If you are stuck at any level, then expand the details into sub-steps.

I would look to separate the problem of working out a sequence of words which will fit onto a line.

Then how many spaces to add between each of the words.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example for printing one line after you find how many words to print and what is the starting word of the line.

```
    std::cout << "|";
    numOfSpaces = lineWidth - numOfCharsUsedByWords;
    /*
     * If we have three words |word1 word2 word3| in a line
     * ideally the spaces to print between then are 1 less than the words
     */
    int spaceChunks = numOfWordsInLine - 1;
    /*
     * Print the words from starting point to num of words
     * you can print in a line
     */
    for (j = 0; j < numOfWordsInLine; ++j) {
        /*
         * Calculation for the number of spaces to print
         * after every word
         */
        int spacesToPrint = 0;
        if (spaceChunks <= 1) {
          /*
           * if one/two words then one 
           * chunk of spaces between so fill then up
           */
           spacesToPrint = numOfSpaces;
        } else {
          /*
           * Here its just segmenting a number into chunks 
           * example: segment 7 into 3 parts, will become 3 + 2 + 2
           *          7 to 3 = (7%3) + (7/3) = 1 + 2 = 3
           *          4 to 2 = (4%2) + (4/2) = 0 + 2 = 2
           *          2 to 1 = (2%1) + (2/1) = 0 + 2 = 2
           */
           spacesToPrint = (numOfSpaces % spaceChunks) + (numOfSpaces / spaceChunks);
        }
        numOfSpaces -= spacesToPrint;
        spaceChunks--;
        cout << words[j + lineStartIdx];
        for (int space = 0; space < spacesToPrint; space++) {
            std::cout << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "|" << std::endl;
```

Hope this code helps. Also you need to consider what happens if you set width less then the max word size.